# TypeError: Cannot read property 'hash' of null

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, vercel

I'm running into issues deploying to Vercel after making some changes.
Running with `npm run dev` works but after deploying to Vercel (which runs with `npm run build`) it coughs up an error:

> 09:53:00.125   TypeError: Cannot read property 'hash' of null
> 09:53:00.125        at callback (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:59190:46)
> 09:53:00.125        at /vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:57683:39
> 09:53:00.125        at /vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:135587:5
> 09:53:00.125        at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:33832:10), :6:1)
> 09:53:00.126        at AsyncQueue._handleResult (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:135557:21)
> 09:53:00.126        at /vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:135540:11
> 09:53:00.126        at /vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:59794:14
> 09:53:00.126        at /vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:59452:6
> 09:53:00.126        at done (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/neo-async/async.js:1:10308)
> 09:53:00.126        at /vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:59356:13
> 09:53:00.126        at /vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:135587:5
> 09:53:00.126        at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:33832:10), :6:1)
> 09:53:00.127        at AsyncQueue._handleResult (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:135557:21)
> 09:53:00.127        at /vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:135540:11
> 09:53:00.127        at Array. (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:59296:4)
> 09:53:00.128        at runCallbacks (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:20480:15)
> 09:53:00.155    Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1

Sorry if the formatting makes it hard to read, I'm not too sure how to copy over the error log without the format running.

All I changed can be boiled down to adding a `Layout` component which uses `NavBar, and Footer` components. I then modified the `_app.js` file to use said layout:

```
import React from "react";
import App from "next/app";
import "tailwindcss/tailwind.css";
import Layout from "../components/Layout";

class MyApp extends App {
  render() {
    const { Component, pageProps, router } = this.props;

    if (router.pathname.startsWith("/shop/")) { //router path check to include/exclude Layout e.g: paths starting with /shop
      return (
        <Layout>
          <Component {...pageProps}></Component>
        </Layout>
      );
    }

    return <Component {...pageProps}></Component>;
  }
}

export default MyApp;
```

Any insights regarding this error is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't change anything, after pushing to Vercel again the error didn't pop up, so its "fixed" now I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Don't we import Component which is a reserved keyword from react module like below and used for extending a class

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
class SomeNavComponent extends Component {
```

Also, it looks like the issue is with the naming of a component, in my opinion

```
const { Component, pageProps, router } = this.props;
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, but it fixed itself without having to change anything. I just had to push to vercel again. Weird, but it is what it is I guess.